# video not working on all android devices

Tags: android, video

I have an app on google play. The app basically is a set of menus, each eventually leads to a video. For some reason, some users complain that one of the menus fails to show its videos, while others have no problem to see these videos. All the machines I tested my app on showed these videos.
How do I deal with that? Where do I start looking for the problem? I asked some of the users that couldn't see the videos for their android version and type of device and they all use common devices and updated android versions, just like some of the machines I tests on successfully.
It can't be a code problem, as I use the same code for all the menus. All videos are of the same type (mp4), all saved in the same server.
What can it possibly be?

Comment: Google play will usually give you the crash reports. It's hard to help without those. Please post them :)

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know the developer console gives that info.